# How to unwrap Vue DOM element and retain its position

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuepress

I am using VuePress, which generates Markdown to HTML. Each Markdown element gets rendered inside of a `<p>` tag. However, I would like to modify the generated HTML document by unwrapping the `<p>` tag when it contains an image or video.

I have added my code into the `mounted()` Vue lifecycle hook of a page (component).

This works: when I access another page first, the unwrapped content appears in the same place as its parent was.

This does not work: accessing the page directly, the content appears below the rest of the Markdown content on the page. Not in its original position.

```js
const elements = this.$refs.content.$el.querySelectorAll("p img, p video"); // Note: Using document.querySelectorAll yields the same results
Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {
  let elParentNode = el.parentNode;
  if (elParentNode !== document.body) {
    elParentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, elParentNode);
    elParentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elParentNode);
  }
});
```

Requirements:

- The unwrapped content (img, video) should appear exactly where the parent content originally was, not below all the other content.
- This should work when the component is access directly and when navigated to.
- No reliance on jQuery